# Is there a way I can run 3 CreateWindow functions at once?

Tags: c++, winapi

I working on my new program about asking the user if he agree to the terms.

My program is creating a black window with a checkbox, when the user check the checkbox,
an button called "RUN" created.
My problem is that I can't change the color of the static text next to the checkbox, I must create first the checkbox and then create and change the static text.

Let me explain, my WM_CREATE is using three CreateWindow functions, one is the checkbox and after it comes the "RUN" button, and the last one is the static text, next to the checkbox.
Now, when I create first the button, the button work well and I can check it and uncheck it, but the static text is not working well.
For the static text I removed his background and change his color with WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC, but the background is not removed and the color too.

Now, when I create first the text, the text is working well and the color and the background are changed, and the button isn't working, I can't check it or uncheck it.

Please try to debug my program, it is hard to explain.
You need to try to switch between the two functions in the WM_CREATE, try to create first text and then you can see that the checkbox is not working well.

My whole program:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

// Text
#define IDC_STATIC 1

// Buttons
#define IDC_BUTTON 2

HWND agree, button1, text;

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcessMessages(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM param, LPARAM lparam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE currentInstance, HINSTANCE previousInstance, PSTR cmdLine, INT cmdCount)
{
    // Register the window class
    const char* CLASS_NAME = "myWin32WindowClass";
    WNDCLASS wc{};
    wc.hInstance = currentInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;
    wc.hIcon = 0;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(20, 20, 20));
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcessMessages;
    RegisterClass(&wc);

    HWND main = CreateWindow(CLASS_NAME, "WastedBit  1.6.2",
        WS_VISIBLE,     // Window style
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,               // Window initial position
        950, 750,                       // Window size
        nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);

    // TopMost
    SetWindowPos(main, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);

    // Window loop
    MSG msg{};
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcessMessages(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE: {
        button1 = CreateWindow("button", 0, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_CHECKBOX, 20, 490, 15, 15, hwnd, (HMENU)1, ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lparam)->hInstance, NULL);

        agree = CreateWindow("button", "RUN", WS_CHILD, 750, 525, 150, 150, hwnd, 0, 0, 0);

        text = CreateWindow("static", "By checking this button, you agree to the terms above", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 30, 490, 150, 150, hwnd, (HMENU)IDC_STATIC, 0, 0);
    }
    break;
    case WM_COMMAND: {
        BOOL checked = IsDlgButtonChecked(hwnd, 1);
        if (checked) {
            CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 1, BST_UNCHECKED);
            ShowWindow(agree, SW_HIDE);
        }
        else {
            CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 1, BST_CHECKED);
            ShowWindow(agree, SW_SHOW);
        }
    }
    break;
    case WM_DESTROY: {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    }
    break;
    case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC: {
        if ((HWND)lparam == GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_STATIC))
        {
            SetBkMode((HDC)wparam, TRANSPARENT);
            SetTextColor((HDC)wparam, RGB(400, 0, 0));
            return (BOOL)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
        }
        break;
    }
    break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
    }
}
```

I have tried to use it with valueless functions, but still the same.

Comment: Instead of doing all this, have you considered just creating multiple static (or other) controls layered on top of each other, and just hiding / unhiding the ones you need at certain times?  That should have the same effect as creating controls at runtime depending on certain criteria.  Less clumsy also.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Hey, What have I done ? I have only created three CreateWindow functions, and I have some problems with it, I don't need to hide anything except my "RUN" button.

Comment: *Please try to debug my program* -- There is no `resource.h` file.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You can remove it, it just an icon to my exe file.

Comment: @drescherjm I will edit.

Comment: @drescherjm I have edit it.

Comment: [Why do dialog editors start assigning control IDs with 100?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041214-00/?p=37013)

Comment: @IInspectable I didn't know that, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you have same child-window identifiers.

Change:

```
button1 = CreateWindow("button", 0, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_CHECKBOX, 20, 490, 15, 15, hwnd, (HMENU)1, ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lparam)->hInstance, NULL);
```

to something:

```
#define ID_BUTTON_2    101

button1 = CreateWindow("button", 0, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_CHECKBOX, 20, 490, 15, 15, hwnd, (HMENU)ID_BUTTON_2, ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lparam)->hInstance, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you receive `WM_COMMAND`, you should check `WM_COMMAND` source.

You created 3 controls, so, they can send you `WM_COMMAND`.

`WM_COMMAND` source can be known from control id ( parameter `HMENU` of `CreateWindow` ).

Here is quick fix.

```
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if( wparam == 1 ) {
            BOOL checked = IsDlgButtonChecked(hwnd, 1);
            if (checked) {
               CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 1, BST_UNCHECKED);
               ShowWindow(agree, SW_HIDE);
            }
            else {
                CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 1, BST_CHECKED);
                ShowWindow(agree, SW_SHOW);
           }
       }
    }
    break;
```